Different types have the same mangled name?
Suppose I have a code like this, compiled in 32-bit C++ Builder with the new tool-chain (i.e. the "Use Classic compiler" option is turned off):
enum class i : char;

   i a1;
   const std::type_info& ti1 = typeid(a1);
   OutputDebugStringA(ti1.name()); // outputs "$i"

   int a2;
   const std::type_info& ti2 = typeid(a2);
   OutputDebugStringA(ti2.name()); // outputs "$i"

Notice how two completely distinct types produce the same mangled/decorated name. In other words, there is a collision when your custom type's real/undecorated name is the same as mangled/decorated name of some other (known/buildin) type.
However, when compiled in x64: the code outputs "1i" for the a1 and "i" for the a2 - which is different from each other. In other words, custom types and aliases for known types do not overlap each other.
Am I missing something?

The standard doesn't specify the name. Here it says "No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types"

typeid.name() has nothing to do with the type names the compiler uses internally when compiling

Gcc and Clang are giving different outputs: https://godbolt.org/z/n478evEE6 (same with -m32 switch).

See wiki: 64-bit Windows compiler based on Clang 3.1. The 32-bit compiler was still based on Embarcadero's older technology. - so this is most probably source of difference between 32 and 64 bits.

A char enum, regardless of its underlying type, is implicitly treated as an integer in any static context. Hence it is reasonable for typeid to report it as such.

See this answer in the dupe that says: "The return of name is implementation defined : an implementation is not even required to return different strings for different types. What you get from g++ is a decorated name, that you can "demangle" using the c++filt command or __cxa_demangle.
"

I agree that it would be nice if name returned the actual name of the type. This is called a "quality of implementation" issue in compiler developer's jargon: any behavior is standard-compliant, but some compilers are better than others in this regard.

The standard doesn't specify the name. Here it says "No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types"

–
BoP
Try ti1 == ti2 to discover that the types are different.

perhaps worth mentioning that this isnt the "mangled name" as OP seems to assume
